# How to design cloud based filesystem via osxFUSE

Tags: macos, fuse

Currently i'm working on [FUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io) based filesystem, that loads file from cloud and stores in local cache.

On user side im using obj-c framework, that wraps Fuse C high level API.

User can see all his files from cloud storage in a listing of a mounted drive. It is just 'ghost' files, not actually stored in local cache.

When user double click on a file, downloading of a file starting.
Under the hood, i block every 'readFileAtPath' call from fuse, till requested chunk of a file data is loaded.

That leads to different freezing issues in Finder and other apps.

For example, when file loading and a reads calls blocked, 'contentsOfDirectoryAtPath' is also blocked - user can't browse a drive, it appears empty, or folders content is incomplete.

I cant respond with error when user clicked on a file, i should download it and provide it content.

Now i'm thinking, is it a correct way to implement such functionality? 
Anyone with similar requirements who resolved such issues?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Did you configure fuse to be multithreaded? That should at least not freaze the other calls

Comment: it's configured multithreaded, but fuse itself contains internal locks which leads to freezing issues.

Comment: I don't know of any locks that freeze other worker threads while one worker thread (read) is blocked. Could it be issues in the client side (Finder)? Is there a possibility to start streaming partial chunks of the data while it's downloading to not let _read_ hang?